# Updated @Published vars from Pickers won't pass their new values to Button function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an asynchronous function that performs an SQL query and updates the @Published variables. I can read these new values into the Picker as the Picker's default value but when I change the Picker value - and then pass it to another function that runs an SQL Update function (through a button), it just passes the original default @Published values, not the updated ones chosen by the user interaction with the Picker. The `findSingleProduct` function is called by passing a Barcode to it that comes from a preceeding view using user input.

```
class ProductsModel: ObservableObject{

    @Published var Comp1Mat: Int = 0
    @Published var code: String = ""

    func findSingleProduct(code: String){
        // Completes an SQL query on the Products database to find a product by it's barcode number.
        // prepare json data
        let insertProductURL = URL(string: "http://recyclingmadesimple.xyz/service.php")!
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: insertProductURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    
        let postString = "code=\(code)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.Comp1Mat = responseJSON["Comp1Mat"] as! Int
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

This is my view that displays Pickers about the object. I have removed a lot of the Pickers as they're all suffering from the same problem so the solution should be transferable.

```
struct ProductDetail: View {
    
        @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ProductsModel()
        init(ad: [String], material: [String], code: String){
            self.viewModel.findSingleProduct(code: code)
            
            }
    
        var body: some View {
    
            //This is the main stack that contains everything
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
    
                Picker(selection: $viewModel.Comp1Mat, label: Text("Material")){
                    ForEach(0 ..< material.count){
                        Text(self.material[$0])
                    }
                }

                Button(action: {viewModel.updateProduct(brands: "\(viewModel.Comp1Mat)", **Omitted variables for simplicity, they also run on similar Pickers**); showingAlert = true}, label: {
                    Text("Update Product")
                }).alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Product Updated"), message: Text("Thanks for helping the community!"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")))
                }
}
```

I have confirmed the PHP and SQL of the update function work by hardcoding some values into the Button like: `Button(action: {viewModel.updateProduct(Comp1Mat: "(5)"}...` and they are indeed correctly passed through and the database is updated.

I thought this similar question might be of use but I believe I am already using the $ correctly, which was the suggested solution for this person so I am unsure why it doesn't work for me. [Change a @Published var via Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66258865/change-a-published-var-via-picker)

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add tag ``` Text(self.material[$0]).tag($0)```

Comment: I believe this has worked, thanks. I will add it to my other Pickers to check it doesn't cause any weird problems but if not I will come back and tag you so you can add it as an answer so I can accept it please. :)

Comment: @RajaKishan this has worked perfectly thank you. Please can you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a tag.

```
Text(self.material[$0]).tag($0)
```